# Pause main thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, gpio

I'm writing some code in Python so that it shows me info on LCD display when I press a button. This is part of my code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def action1(self):
   temp = "15"
   lcd.clear()
   lcd.message("  Temp. Est.: \n" + "    " + temp + " " + chr(223) + "C")
   time.sleep(5.0) 
   lcd.clear

GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.RISING,callback=action1, bouncetime=800) 

while True:
date = datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')
lcd.message(date)
time.sleep(5.0)
lcd.clear()
```

This code is working but when I press the button it shows me the temperature, then the time and the temperature again (it depends on when I press the button). I've read that "GPIO.add_event_detect" runs a second thread for callback functions and it does not pause the main thread. I would like that after the button is pressed it stays on the LCD whenever i push the button and then it starts the code from bottom, in my case with the time.
How may I achieve it? Thank you!

Comment: You could "debounce" it yourself by capturing the time of the button press and ignoring button presses that follow too quickly.  The answer to this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8544/gpio-interrupt-debounce  might help.

Comment: How fast does the displayed value toggle? Your button is probably bouncing. You may read this: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/

Comment: Maybe you got me wrong or I got you wrong but the problem here are not repeated button presses. The problem is that the code I always want to show is in a while loop and the display alternates between the code inside the main thread and the other thread opened by GPIO.add_event_detect

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is full of counter-intuitive surprises. To avoid them, I'd rather avoid updating the display from two different threads.

Instead, I'd rather send a message from the handler thread, or at least updated a shared flag from it.

The main loop would run faster and react on the updates (a rough sketch):

```
desired_state = None  # the shared flag, updated from key press handler.
current_state = 'show_date'  # what we used to display
TICK = 0.1  # we check the state every 100 ms.
MAX_TICKS = 50  # we display a value for up to 5 seconds.
ticks_elapsed = 0
while True:
  if desired_state != current_state:
    # State changed, start displaying a new thing.
    current_state = desired_state
    ticks_elapsed = 0
    if desired_state == 'show_date':
      put_date_on_lcd()
    elif desired_state == 'show_temp':
      put_temp_on_lcd()
    elif desired_state == 'blank':
      clear_lcd()
    else:  # unknown state, we have an error in the program.
       signal_error('What? %s' % desired_state)
  # Advance the clock.
  time.sleep(TICK)
  ticks_elapsed += 1
  if ticks_elapsed >= MAX_TICKS:
    # Switch display to either date or blank.
    desired_state = 'show_date' if current_state == 'blank' else 'blank' 
    ticks_elapsed = 0
```

Disclaimer: I did not test this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway, I would like to pause/interrupt the process in the main thread when another one is opened by GPIO.add_event_detect to avoid double LCD update by different threads. I can't get it

Comment: Well, update a "stop main thread" flag in the signal handler thread, sleep / check for the flag state in your main thread then? You won't be able to _interrupt_ the main thread in an arbitrary place, though, just to make it wait in a particular place; sort of cooperative multitasking instead of preemptive.